# cast a hex value into a char oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

In teradata we have the concept of casting a hex into a char like the following:

```
select cast(X'0000' AS CHAR(16)) from something;
```

What's the equivalent Oracle representation of this `X''`

Could it be UNISTR?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a series of hexadecimal digits to a number you can use the TO_NUMBER function with the 'X' mask character, as in:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('12AB', 'XXXX') FROM dual;
```

This produces the (decimal) result 4779.

If you want to go the other way, i.e. convert a number to its hexadecimal representation, you can use the TO_CHAR function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(4779, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') FROM dual;
```

which produces the result `'             12AB'`. Note that because the TO_CHAR function leaves room for a sign (`+` or `-`) the returned string is actually 17 characters wide.